# How do I use font awesome with sass

Tags: fonts, sass, font-awesome

I am fairly new to SASS so trying to get my head around using font-face with it. I am struggling getting Font Awesome to work. Here is the SASS Mixin I am using:-

```
@import "compass/css3/font-face";
@include font-face("FontAwesome", font-files("fontawesome-webfont.ttf", "FontAwesome.otf", "fontawesome-webfont.woff", "fontawesome-webfont.svg", "fontawesome-webfont.eot"));
```

I have then assigned a font to a variable:-

```
$fontawesome: 'FontAwesome', Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

And assigned the font to the body tag in the CSS.

However, it just defaults to helvetica and I can't get any font awesome icons.

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like?  Are the font files in the correct location or are you getting a 404?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570424/using-fontawesome-with-sass