# How to Set up font-awesome on Sass

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome-3.2

I'm fairly new to Sass and I'm trying to set up font-awesome for my web development projects. I've just installed the gem through the terminal (I'm using a mac) which went succesfull. Also in my `<head>..</head>` I'm linking to MAXCDN and hope to download as less files as possible.

If I'm correct I shouldn't download any files since I'm using MAXCDN, is this correct?

I came across this link:[Using FontAwesome with Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570424/using-fontawesome-with-sass) which explains a lot, but doesn't answer my question. 
This link explains how to set it up if you're downloading font-awesome. 
But I prefer not to download it and just link it to MAXCDN inside my `<head>..</head>`.

I don't want to download font-awesome for every project.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, at least explain why so I can learn from it.

Comment: If you import the css from cdn in your sass this will work like you want, as a link to cdn file.