# installing font awesome and sass

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-awesome

Im trying to install font awesome to my simple sass project i have.

1 simple html page linking to 1 css file that is spit out via my sass.

Is there anyway of installing it locally to that project folder?

I couldnt see anything on the website

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

You have to link it through ruby rails.
Ive managed to import font awesome but the icon just shows up as a box so i think its looking for the missing svg.

Answer (score -2):

Try to this:

Go to this site: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

and Click no Download Folder.

Add font-awesome.css stylesheet in your head tag &
Add font folder also, Please give font path proper in the font-awesome.css stylesheet.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css][1]"/>
</head>
```

Comment: i need to use it in sass.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570424/using-fontawesome-with-sass @RobertWilding

Comment: He's not the only one with this problem. And it's not an answer to the question.